# Populating child objects in SDN4 in a convenient way

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In SDN3.4.0 when an entity is loaded from database, empty child objects (no @Fetch annotation) are populated with only ids present. In SDN4 this doesn't happen and child objects are not populated with ids (for depth 0). Wanted to understand the reason for this change ?

Is there a way to directly populate child objects in SDN4 when entities are queried using complex cypher queries either from session or repository (using @Query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default load level is 1 when using the session or repository load methods. This means all objects directly related to the entity are loaded.
You can override this depth.

@Query does not support depth specification at the moment.

Comment: Can you answer first part of my question. Thanks.

Comment: It's because SDN4 is re-written from scratch to primarily support the "remote" use case, i.e. cypher over the wire as opposed to direct Java API access to embedded Neo4j.